# Rose Katherine Morton

Tags: mathematicians

I stumbled upon something called The Morton Number, I wonder if anyone knows about it? I found out that it is related to Rose Katherine Morton, I know she was an american mathematician, but very little information on the web about her. So i started a wikipedia page (waiting for review), so people can contribute more to it.

I think she invented (with some of her colleagues (if i am not mistaken)) something called the Morton number and has something to do with fluid flow dynamics and bubble behaviour.

I think she got a Bachelor's degree and was also involved in mechanical engineering. There's also something called Morton number in binary where the states of the bits are duplicated, but i have no idea if these two are related. If you have or can dig up some more information about her, that would be great.

Comment: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.1024.4141&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: yes sir, I forgot to mention that paper. thx

Comment: https://www.findagrave.com/memorial/1154518/rose-katherine-sayre

Comment: This might be better suited for https://hsm.stackexchange.com